# Can't access Wordpress multisite after connecting to domain

Tags: multisite, directory, dns

Installed `Wordpress` `Subdirectory` `Multisite` on `Vultr` server, connected Google Domain, but can't access it. It is showing ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT.

When checking `DNS`, A records are fine, but `CNAME` records are not. Can't understand why, as in Vultr side I can't add any cname records ( currently it has- cname * mydomain.com)

In `PowerShell` I ran `tracert` and receive a response as 14 hops and it goes to my Vultr IP. But when typing in the domain name it still shows the error. I tried adding define lines `siteurl` and homeurl in wp-config.php with my domain name, but still no luck. 
Can someone suggest how this can be fixed so I can reach my Wordpress site?

Comment: does the readme.html load? You should fix your CNAME records, contact your DNS provider for help with that, DNS isn't a WP thing though so we can't help you with DNS issues on this stack

Comment: Contacted the hosting and with dns records everything seems fine. The problem might be  in database, as I currently can access my subfolder site, but can't access the main domain, as it is showing- Error establishing a database connection. Also I can't get into the database, in wp.config file, the site url and homeurl are fine. When tried to repair the database, for main site it still showed that can't connect, but for subfolder site it allowed to repair it which didn't fix anything, as I still have no access to main domain.

Comment: It sounds like you have yet to identify the thing you want to ask about, and still need to do debugging and investigative steps to find out what's actually wrong. Eitherway it sounds like you did something and things broke, but haven't mentioned what you did, or if it's always been this way, etc. If it's a brand new fresh install I'd be tempted to just erase and reinstall, but right now there's nowhere near enough actionable information to answer this